# Drawing lines with rounded endings with Direct3D

Tags: directx, direct3d, slimdx

Is there any way to draw a line using ID3DXLine with round endings? I am trying to draw a curve from number of line segments, but getting the empty areas where the line segments are connecting. 
Performance here is essential.

Thanks!

---

Any other fast way to draw thick curved line using D3D?

Answer (score 2):

You would be best off using a circular texture (with antialiasing around the edges) and then drawing half the texture at either end of the line. You can then render a strip through the center of the texture the whole way along a rectangle surrounding the line before finishing off with the other half of the texture at the other end.  This will give you the effect you are after but its a tad more involved than simply calling "DrawLine" or whatever ...